# Problems with Pandas corr() function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, correlation

Trying to get a correlation matrix in using pandas.DataFrame.corr() but for some reason it's only returning 1 column.
[image]

Comment: implies "Quizzes" and "Assignments" are seemingly numeric but perhaps really strings

Comment: what do you have on `df_APStats.dtypes`?  `.corr` only works for numeric dtypes.

Answer (score 0):

I replicate your situation on my system google colab and it works perfectly.

version that i use:

```
python version: 3.7.14
pandas version: 1.3.5
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/content/TEST.csv') # create dataset from your image that you 
                                      #post in your question and load it into data frame

print(df[['Unit 1 MC', 'Quizzes', 'Assignments']])

df[['Unit 1 MC', 'Quiz', 'Assig']].corr()
```